# Is compiling compass to public/ dir in rails safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, compass-sass

I have my .scss files stored in the app/assets/stylesheets folder in Rails 3.x.  When I compile the folder (using: compass compile ~/projects/myproject), the resulting .css files are placed in a newly created folder public/assets.  I guess this is the default behavior.

My question is, for security and best practice, is it safe to have Compass compile the css files to the public folder?

If it is not a good thing, how can I tell compass to compile the css files elsewhere?  Is there a command I can add to a config file somewhere?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is totally secure. The Rails Assets Pipeline behaves, by convention, exactly this way too. The public folder is the place where all your assets are put when compiled. In the same way, the SCSS compiled by Compass are secure there.